# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastprogress' when running wand agent

Tags: python, windows, modulenotfounderror, wand

I have been facing this problem when I try to run a wand agent after configuring the sweep:

```console
wandb agent rca-dev/pis_course/xxxxxxxx --count 1 
wandb: Starting wandb agent ️
2023-10-07 22:56:21,768 - wandb.wandb_agent - INFO - Running runs: []
2023-10-07 22:56:22,215 - wandb.wandb_agent - INFO - Agent received command: run
2023-10-07 22:56:22,216 - wandb.wandb_agent - INFO - Agent starting run with config:
        batch_size: 16
        image_size: 512
        learning_rate: 0.00018268998599127624
        model_arch: resnet18
        seed: 2
2023-10-07 22:56:22,217 - wandb.wandb_agent - INFO - About to run command: python train.py --batch_size=16 --image_size=512 --learning_rate=0.00018268998599127624 --model_arch=resnet18 --seed=2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\renan\source\repos\pyimagesearch-mlops-with-weights-biases\train.py", line 8, in <module>
    from fastprogress import progress_bar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastprogress'
2023-10-07 22:56:27,226 - wandb.wandb_agent - INFO - Running runs: ['43rwcdgm']
2023-10-07 22:56:27,227 - wandb.wandb_agent - INFO - Cleaning up finished run: 43rwcdgm
wandb: Terminating and syncing runs. Press ctrl-c to kill.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

I tried to replace fastprogress package with tqdm but the same error happens. I also tried to remove the fastprogress package but the execution triggers an error at the following import which is the timm one. By the way, all mentioned packages here are installed.